# How to storage an image in MongoDB with pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, fastapi

I'm doing a simple CRUD with FastAPI to store an image and its information in MongoDB, so far this is my code:

```
@app.post("/postImage")
async def image_post(id: str, author: str, title: str, file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    
    file.filename = f"{uuid.uuid4()}.jpg"
    contents = await file.read()

    image = base64.b64decode(contents)
 
    data = {"_id": id, "author": author, "title": title ,"data": image, "posted": False,"uploaded": datetime.now()}

    try:
      collection.insert_one(data)
    except:
        print('Error')

    return("Added successfully")
```

However, when I'm trying to convert the bytes to string it returns me an error.

```
image = base64.b64decode(contents)
print(image.decode('utf-8'))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 11: invalid start byte
```

I've tried many alternatives, but I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Did you want `image = base64.b64encode(contents)` before inserting the document?  Or maybe just store it as BSON binary data?

Comment: I'm trying to store it as a string so I can use it later in the get function

Comment: "store it as a string" your database and future you will hate every part of this idea. just save it as a file, on a proper file storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mongo](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/gridfs/#:%7E:text=In%20MongoDB%2C%20use%20GridFS%20for,as%20many%20files%20as%20needed.) suggest this to store files bigger than 16mb (GridFS)

I suggest you do this:
First create directory in your project named "static" then do this

```
import uuid
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi import UploadFile, File, status
import aiofiles

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")


@app.post("/")
async def post_endpoint(in_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    random_name = uuid.uuid4()
    async with aiofiles.open(f"static/{random_name}.jpg", "wb") as out_file:
        while content := await in_file.read(1024):  # async read chunk
            await out_file.write(content)


    return {"Result": "OK"}
```

and then save your file name in db like string.

for get image you can use this :
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/uuiduuiduuiduuiduuiduuiduuid.jpg